# Coming up with short "magical" proofs

Tags: soft-question, problem-solving

I was reading the solution to this problem:

Prove that $f(n) = 2n$ is the only non-constant solution to $2f (m^2 + n^2 ) = (f (m))^2 + (f (n))^2 .$

The solution used these identities, pulled out of the blue:

$(5k + 1)^2 + 2^2 = (4k + 2)^2 + (3k − 1)^2 ,$

$(5k + 2)^2 + 1^2 = (4k + 1)^2 + (3k + 2)^2 ,$

$(5k + 3)^2 + 1^2 = (4k + 3)^2 + (3k + 1)^2 ,$

$(5k + 4)^2 + 2^2 = (4k + 2)^2 + (3k + 4)^2 ,$

$(5k + 5)^2 + 0^2 = (4k + 4)^2 + (3k + 3)^2 .$

and proceeded to use strong induction to prove the hypothesis.

As I have spent more and more time studying mathematics, I see more of these "magic" solutions in which some obscure identity or property is pulled out of nowhere and used to facilitate a proof...often, multiple such jumps are used in a proof...and these proofs are meant to be done in an hour or so. I feel discouraged by this, because I don't understand how to do these "magical" things. I feel like I could spend 10 years trying to solve this problem, and still fail, because I don't have magical powers.

How can I improve myself? How do I learn to come up with magical proofs like these? I feel like practicing problem solving is useless because I can solve all the easy ones...but the moment a "hard" problem comes, I can't solve it at all. So I read the solution, and understand it, but the next problem is completely different and uses a different magical identity and so I haven't actually *learned* anything.

I'm sorry for ranting here, but I feel hopeless. I'm 19 and some people my age are solving these problems easily. Do I lack mathematical ability genetically or is is something I can gain through practice? I am wondering if I am just wasting my best years studying mathematics when I don't have the genes for it.

EDIT: For those asking why I couldn't just use a substitution...the actual problem was . to find *all* solutions, not just $f(n)=2n$

Comment: Hey now--I'm 19 and I'm nowhere near close to solving that problem.  `;)`  The important thing to keep in mind is that, no matter your skill level, there will *always* be someone better *and* someone worse than you in at least one topic.  Don't focus on being the best--focus on doing your best and being the best comes naturally.

Comment: When I'm trying to write a proof of something, and I manage to get the result I usually go back and start looking for weird identities and shortcuts etc. that I could use to write a short "elegant" proof. IMO I think that's just what a lot of authors do.

Comment: I don't see why anyone would solve this by citing these identities.  You can just evaluate both sides with $f(n) = 2n$ and see that they come out the same.

Comment: Thank you so much for not using the word 'mathemagic' in your post

Comment: Can't you just prove it directly? It seems like if $f(n)=2n$ then $2f(m^2+n^2)=4m^2+4n^2=(2m)^2+(2n)^2=f(m)^2+f(n)^2$.  Do you want to prove that $f(n)=2n$ is the only such solution?

Comment: @Ethan Thank you for changing the title. I've added the tags soft-question and proof-writing, as I think they describe more accurately the idea of the question.

Comment: @Thomas it seems it isn't the only such solution. Haven't looked through, but there are the trivial $f(n)=0$ and $f(n)=1$. It might be the only non-constant solution, but I haven't tried.

Comment: These particular "magical" relationships come from multiple factorizations of Gaussian integers. Gaussian integers often come up when dealing with problems about summing two squares.

Comment: But it helps to understand the problem @Ethan. Is this a case where the proof is a "joke" - there is a one line proof of what he stated - or is it a case where it is necessary?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews The latter. I edited the OP.

Comment: I think you should not attempt to train yourself to produce magical proofs. As you have already seen, other people learn very little from these. You should train yourself to produce understandable proofs that teach people things.

Comment: There are three main rules in mathematics: you can't win, you can't cheat, and the stack is rigged against you. So smile! Because tomorrow will be even worse. Which is why you should just relax, and enjoy today. But just like a man can never give up on women just because he was unlucky so far, so a true mathematician could never conceive of letting go of his passion for this form of art, no matter how rare and underwhelming his realizations might be. Cheers! :-)

Answer (score 2):

There are ways to learn how to come up with "magic tricks", some are described in Polya's [books](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/How_to_Solve_It). But perhaps that is not the right approach for you. Grothendieck, arguably the greatest mathematical genius of last century, describes this approach as thinking of "a theorem to be proved as a nut to be opened", and says that it is not his. He likens his approach to the [rising sea](https://www.imj-prg.fr/~leila.schneps/grothendieckcircle/mclarty1.pdf) where the theorem is “submerged and dissolved by some more or less vast theory, going well beyond the results originally to be established”. Once you get a solution from such a comprehensive study it is sometimes possible to simplify and shorten it into a few lines that look like "magic". Many proofs and solutions that you will encounter will look this way, but that's not how their authors found them.

As Thomas Andrews pointed out, if you knew of Gaussian integers and saw this functional equation you would probably think of applying their properties to it, and come up with these identities. Maybe studying mathematical theories and methods systematically would suit you more than chasing after individual problems with clever tricks. I'd also like to point out that according to studies kids who believe in "genetic abilities" are less likely to work hard and more likely to give up quickly when things don't go easy for them. But working hard is always a must, so those "abilities" often become self-fulfilling prophecies.

There is more than one way to be a mathematician, you'll have to find yours, and 19 is still very young. If you like mathematics try different areas, different styles before you decide to give up.

Comment: Thank you very much for this comment. Your point about giving up quickly due to a belief in genetic abilities spoke to me. I realize now that I have to stop whining like a little bitch and start working harder.

Comment: As regards the simplification of a proof, I like to say that the first stage is in finding some proof. Even a long, ugly proof. One then proceeds to find a prettier proof. This can sometimes be the lion's share of the work. Finding elegant, "magic" tricks to quickly solve a problem comes mostly from experience and breadth. Math has a vast array of interconnections, and it should not be underestimated how a working knowledge of a field and topic far from your specific interests can open new avenues of discovery in the topics you most enjoy.